# Unable to get SPField named 'FieldName'

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, sputility

I keep getting an error every time I am trying to insert some jquery/sputility code to get a SharePoint form field to be hidden if certain conditions are met. The error is "Unable to get SPField named ExternalSales". Here is the code:

```js
<script src="<sharepoint site>/test/Shared Documents/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<sharepoint site>/test/SiteAssets/sputility.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var externalsales = SPUtility.GetSPField('ExternalSales');
var showOrHideField = function() {
var externalsalesValue = externalsales.GetValue();
if (externalsalesValue == 'No') {
SPUtility.HideSPField('PPE');
}
else {
SPUtility.ShowSPField('PPE');
}
};
showOrHideField();
$(externalsales.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
});
</script>
```

With regards to the SPUtility syntax, how do I find out the strFieldName? I'm assuming that's the part that's incorrect.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that's your filed Display Name, may be you need to use `External Sales` (with a space)?

**UPD**:
There is also a method `SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName`, if you know the internal name, this approach is preferable over display name.

Comment: I tried both, but I'm still getting the same error. Just a little more information, I am using a script editor web part on the same page as the SharePoint form. Does this matter, or does the script need to be somewhere else? I was thinking you might have to reference the form somewhere in the script, but I'm quite new to scripting in SharePoint so wasn't overly sure.

Comment: Normally it's ok, the script should on the form.